# LTSpice: Find settling time using .meas

Tags: simulation, ltspice

I want to find the settling time (i.e. the voltage at `C1` not leaving a band of 1% anymore) of a step response in a circuit like this:

[image: Simple circuit]

The step response looks like this:

[image: Step response]

As I have a more complicated case and a lot of variables I want to determine the settling time efficiently using the `.meas` command. The trigger would be the rising edge of `V1`, but how can I find the point in time, where the response won't leave my 1% band anymore? The number of oscillations is not known.

Comment: Will the circuit always be the same (with varying component values)?

Comment: yes. I'll have several nested `.step` commands to permutate my configurations. The netlist will stay the same, only values change.

Comment: Why don't you simple use the mathematical approach: calculate the damping \$\alpha\$, determine the applicable solution and find when the exponential term decays such that the result is 1%.

Comment: Because my real network is much more complex, including transmission lines and real operational amplifiers.

Comment: So, your circuit is not the same in contrary to your first comment.

Comment: @Huisman I think he meant that his complex network will stay the same and only the `.step`ped parameters change, while you probably referred to the 1st picture.

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
.meas tmp find V(o) when abs(v(o)-1)=0.01 fall=last
```

Alternatively, you can concoct something like this for a more "dynamical" approach:

[image: test]

I commented out the `.step` card so that the results are a bit more visible. This is just one approach. Note that this implies knowing the I/O step value(s). I suppose you can do that by simple subtraction, but you know what cases you have for that.

Comment: This is great! Is there any possibility to specify a maximum time for the search for the "last" fall?

Comment: @DPF I don't think you can, but there is an option to specify the delay from which the count starts, `td=<...>[seconds]`, which can be appended to the command line. Though, I tried recreating the circuit now, and with or without `td`, the same results appeared, both in IV and XVII. Also, instead of `[...] find V(o) [...]`, you can use `[...] find time [...]` to find the `time`, directly, but the way I wrote it allows you to also see the value of `V(o)`.